# Где найти адекватную документацию к torch?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

все найденные мною гайды показывают только вывод квадратика с классом, я так и не смог найти документацию в которой бы говорилось как мне получение название классов, координаты и точность найденных объектов для работы с ними в кодe.

```
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp5/weights/best.pt', force_reload=True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    results = model(frame)
    
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

подскажите, что возвращает "results = model(frame)" или ссылки где можно посмотреть примеры получения нужных мне значений.

Answer (score 0):

Чем [это](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) не адекватная документация? А [тут](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html) ответ на ваш вопрос

P.S. если не знаете английский включите переводчик